# is there any history at all for this notation of partial anti-derivatives?

Tags: calculus, integration, notation, partial-derivative

i have searched but can not find examples of any published book or online articles that use this notation: $$\int f(x,y) \partial x$$ seems it would be useful for example here: 
$$\int_I\int_J f(x,y)dxdy = \int_I\color{blue}{\left(\color{black}{\int_J f(x,y)}\partial x\right)}dy$$

is there a history of such notation? 
are there problems with such notation?
any thoughts/help would be much appreciated
thx

edited->
some background for the question.. a student writes
$$A=xy$$
then writes
$$dA=xdy+ydx$$
then the student tries to recover the A by integrating
$$\int dA=\int ydx+\int xdy$$
which 'yields'
$$A=yx+c(y)+yx+c2(x)=2xy+c(y)+c2(x)$$
which is NOT the correct value of A, the teacher says $\int ydx\ne yx$ the students replies "sometimes it is" we routinely compute  $\int ydx=yx$  when doing the inside of a double integral...so in $\int ydx$ sometimes $y$ is held constant and sometimes not.. yet the notation is indistinguishable...

Comment: It is as unnecessary as $\partial$ instead of $\mathrm d$ is for partial derivatives.

Comment: @GitGud:  Disagree.  $\frac{\partial f(x,x)}{\partial x}$ is gibberish, but $\frac{\mathrm{d} f(x,x)}{\mathrm{d} x}$ is not.  This makes it clear that there is a difference.

Comment: @EricTowers How is the first gibberish and the second not?

Comment: @GitGud:  Partial derivatives are with respect to formal parameters.  Which of the two distinct formal parameters is meant by $x$ there?

Comment: @EricTowers $\partial x$ means it is with respect to the first variable, in fact I've seen the notation $\partial _i f$instead of $\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}$.

Comment: some background for the question.. a student writes $$A=xy$$ then writes $$dA= xdy+ydx$$ then the student tries to recover the $A$ by integrating $$\int dA = \int ydx + \int xdy$$ which 'yields' $$A = yx +c(y) + yx+c_2(x) = 2xy +c(y)+c_2(x)$$ which is NOT the correct value of $A$, the teacher says $\int ydx \ne yx$ the students says then why is $\int ydx = yx$ when doing the inside of a double integral...so in $\int ydx$ sometimes y is held constant and sometimes not.. yet the notation is indistinguishable...

Comment: @GitGud:  Which of "first" exclusive-or "second" is the variable "$x$" in $\frac{\partial f(x,x)}{\partial x}$?

Comment: @EricTowers The first variable is the one after the first parentheses. The notation $\dfrac{\partial f(x,x)}{\partial x}$ is another way of writting $\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x,x)$, that is $\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ evaluated at a given point $(x,x)$ and the meaning of $\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}$is just what it usually is, i.e., it is the function $(a,b)\mapsto \lim \limits_{h\to 0}\left(\dfrac{f(a+h,b)-f(a,b)}{h}\right)$.

Comment: @GitGud:  No.  $f$ is a two-input function; it does not accept a point.

Comment: @EricTowers I don't know what you mean, if the word point troubles you, just replace it with $(x,x)\in \text{dom}(f)$.

Comment: @userX I recommend editing your comment into your original question - wouldn't want it getting lost in the notation fight!

Comment: @GitGud:  What do you write to take the derivative of $f(x,x)$ with respect to its second slot?  There are certainly no "$y$"s here.

Comment: @EricTowers You seem to think $f(x,x)$ is a function, it isn't. The function is $f$, where as $f(x,x)$ denotes the function $f$ evaluated at $(x,x)$. Answering your question, to denote the partial derivative with respect to the second variable one would use $\dfrac {\partial f}{\partial y}$ or $\partial _2 f$. If one wants this evaluated at $(x,x)\in \text{dom}(f)$, one would write  $\dfrac {\partial f}{\partial y}(x,x)$ or $\partial _2 f(x,x)$.

Comment: @DanielLittlewood thx :-)

Comment: @GitGud:  Partially correct and partially incorrect.  $f(x,y) = \dots$ declares formal parameters $x$ and $y$.  It is valid to take partial derivatives with respect to formal parameters and by syntactic substitution with respect to any parameter symbol one chooses to substitute for those parameters.  However, it is still valid to evaluate the function at $(x,x)$, giving $f(x,x)$ and ask what the derivative of that thing is.  It's partial derivative is gibberish since no unambiguous choice of formal parameter is possible.  It's derivative with respect to the external "$x$" is not gibberish.

Comment: @EricTowers You're changing the usual meaning of function by focusing on its syntax. With that meaning, you're right.But that's not what it's done usually.

Comment: @GitGud:  The determination of which strings in a language are gibberish or not is entirely a question of syntax.

Comment: The line "$\mathrm{d}A = x\mathrm{d}y+y\mathrm{d}x$" is already suspect since it muddles which variables are dependent and which are independent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes $x=3$ and sometimes $x=17$. You can't tell which is which if someone just writes $x$! The notation is indistinguishable!

Okay, the comment is a bit snarky, but it illustrates the point: notation is introduced to mean something, and if you ignore the meaning, you have a problem. e.g. if $x$ and $y$ are defined to be functionally related, then it is a flat out *mistake* to imagine that one can vary while the other is held constant.

(nitpick: there are degenerate cases like the relationship being $y = 0$ when $x \leq 0$ and $y = x$ when $x \geq 0$)

Partial derivative notation is already somewhat problematic; I don't think it's a good idea to try and extend it to integrals! e.g. if you are working on the unit sphere, you have three coordinates $x,y,z$ related by the equation $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 1$. Now suppose you have some function $f$ on the sphere. What does $\partial f/\partial x$ mean? Are you supposed to hold $y$ constant while $x$ varies? Or are you supposed to hold $z$ constant? Or something else entirely?

For integrals, there is no ambiguity: the *path of integration* tells you how the variables are related. When we write

$$ \int_0^1 \int_0^1 x y \, dx \, dy $$

what we really mean is that the integral

$$ \int_0^1 x y \, dx $$

is supposed to be taken over the vertical path that starts at $(x,y) = (0,y)$ and ends at $(1,y) = (0,y)$. (Note that each value of $y$ gives a different vertical path!) If you wanted to be pedantic, you could write it explicitly as a path integral; e.g. define $\gamma_y$ to be the path I mention above, and then write the integral as

$$ \int_0^1  \int_{\gamma_y} x y \, dx \, dy $$

In your example with the student's mistake, the problem is that the student never picked a path. When you break the integral apart across a sum, you have to use the same path on all of the integrals; but he chose two different paths on the right hand side. :(

Even worse, if you were in the univariate case (e.g. $x,y,A$ all functions of some variable $t$), then you have to pick the path defined by the relationship between the variables; it doesn't even make sense to imagine $y$ is held constant while $x$ varies!

Comment: very nice! thank you, i actually think $\int_0^1  \int_{\gamma_y} x y \, dx \, dy$ is better because to it addresses the issue i had.. namely that $\int_0^1xydx$ means something in one course then it means something else in another course, it would be nice if the integral operator meant the same thing in most courses.

Comment: but i respectfully disagree on your example with $x$,  as the phrase " $$x=3 \text{ and }  p(x)$$" is different than "$$x=7 \text{ and } p(x)$$" so the notations are distinguishable in that case, similarly as $$\int f(x,y) dx$$ is different than   $$\int  f(x,y) dx \text{ along some path, } \gamma$$ as they should be. The trouble is when we use "$\int f(x,y) dx$" to mean  "$\int  f(x,y) dx$ along some path $\gamma$".... thus i appreciate the pedantic notation you suggested, that's exactly what i was looking for.. thank you

Comment: What about when you're integrating to undo a partial derivative? Like when solving exact differential equations. $x$ and $y$ are related by a function, but with the integral you need to treat one as a constant. And it's an indefinite integral so there's no path

Answer (score 0):

It does not follow from

$$
dA = x \, dy + y\, dx.
$$

that 
$$
\int dA = \int x \, dy + \int y \, dx
$$

Indeed, you gave a proof by contradiction of the above statement. Instead,

$$
\int dA = \int x \, dy + y \, dx
$$

This is a path integral. The teacher might instead respond that if we choose a curve $C$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$of the sort that is susceptible to Green's theorem (and that encloses the region $D$) where $D$ is the region enclosed by $C$, then we would instead be trying to aim for

$$
\oint_C y \, dx + x \, dy = \iint_D \left( \frac{\partial x}{\partial x} - \frac{\partial y}{\partial y} \right) \, dx \, dy \\
= \iint_D \, dx \, dy = \dotsm = xy.
$$

$x \, dy + y \, dx$ is a 1-form; integrating a 1-form is not like Calculus I/II integration.

Comment: Path integrals are additive too: it **is** true that $$\int_C \omega + \nu = \int_C \omega + \int_C \nu$$